# How to decrypt a value in the SelectCommand of ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, password-encryption

Currently I'm testing encryption in SQL Server and the encryption is working as expected. I'm able to insert encrypted values into my table but I'm having difficulty selecting the decrypted values.

If I use

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [password], [username], [id] FROM [encryptionTest]"
```

as my `SelectCommand`, I get the encrypted values from my table. What is the proper syntax to select the decrypted values using the `SelectCommand` in ASP.Net?

When I use query builder on the `SelectQuery` in the properties when the `SelectCommand` is selected, the `SelectCommand` below does return the correct values but when I try to load the aspx page on a browser, it causes a runtime error.

[QueryBuilder Showing Decryption Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkzJb.png)

[QueryBuilder Showing Encrypted Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTD2f.png)

If it helps, I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" 
         AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="encryptionTest.aspx.cs"  
         Inherits="IT_encryptionTest" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="MainContent">
        <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView2" runat="server" OnCustomErrorText="ASPxGridView2_CustomErrorText" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceEncryptionTest" KeyFieldName="id">
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ShowNewButtonInHeader="True" VisibleIndex="0">
                </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="password" VisibleIndex="1">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="username" VisibleIndex="2">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="id" VisibleIndex="3" ReadOnly="True">
                    <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            </Columns>
        </dx:ASPxGridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceEncryptionTest" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GHF_SQLConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Pass_Key_01 DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE TestCert01; SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey(password)) AS Password, [username], [id] FROM [encryptionTest]" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [encryptionTest] WHERE [id] = @id" 
        InsertCommand="OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY Pass_Key_01 DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE TestCert01; INSERT INTO [encryptionTest] ([password], [username]) VALUES (EncryptByKey(Key_GUID('Pass_Key_01'),@password), @username)" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [encryptionTest] SET [password] = @password, [username] = @username WHERE [id] = @id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="password" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="password" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: What's the error?  Is it having a problem with two statements?  If so, maybe putting them in a stored procedure will work.

Comment: I don't believe it's a problem with having 2 statements. If I use the SelectCommand="SELECT [password], [username], [id] FROM [encryptionTest]", my page loads fine even though the InsertCommand has 2 statements. Inserting data works as expected. This is the error though: https://imgur.com/a/FFVIs

Comment: Hey Travis, is this in a test environment so you can turn custom errors off and get the actual exception?

Comment: Oh thanks! I moved it to a test environment, this is my error: https://imgur.com/a/tmdcL

Comment: Looks like you need to change the column name in the select from Password to password (lower case).

Comment: Oh wow. That did it! I didn't think it'd have an issue with the name of my alias. My page now loads and displays the decrypted values. Thanks Obie!

Comment: Great! I learned something too, I haven't messed with these encryption commands before.

Comment: Good to hear, I learned all about it through the Microsoft site. Specifically here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encrypt-a-column-of-data

Comment: Please do not add tags to your question title, including `[solved]` tags, as it may be perceived as unneeded noise by the community. When an answer is accepted, this is an acceptable way to show that the question has been answered.

Comment: fwiw, generally encryption alone is  **not sufficient** for storing password values. You should be salting and cyrptographically **hashing** the password. The difference is hashing is non-reversible. To check someone's credentials you must re-hash the attempted password, and compare the hash values.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Joel. I've read about salting briefly in the Microsoft docs. I'll research these topics and keep them in mind.